# Can I get a p-value testing statistical significance between two coin flipping rounds?

Tags: p-value, binomial-distribution

i'm a graduate student (biology program) with minimal experience with statistics. I have two questions relating to my project that i'd love help with!
The first question is how I can take a single measurement of many events (such as, 55 coin flips out of 100 yielded heads) and test if that is significantly different than a separate measurement (such as, now with a different coin, I see 40 coin flips out of 100 yields heads - so are the two coins significantly different? Can I put a p-value on that?). The second question is, if I use an R program that draws a best fit line on some data and gives i.e. the slope is 10 and the 95% confidence interval is from 8 to 12, then compare that to another slope that is 14 with a 95% CI from 12 to 16, are these results significantly different? And can I put a p-value on that as well? 
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Let's do the coin flip first.  Here is how to do this in R

```
heads<-c(55,40)
flips<-c(100,100)

prop.test(heads,flips, correct = F)
```

The `heads` array houses the number of heads we observed.  The `flips` array houses the number of times each coin was flipped.  The function `prop.test` performs a [test of proportions](https://stattrek.com/hypothesis-test/difference-in-proportions.aspx).  You can see the p-value in the print out.

As for the regression, I don't think you can do this without access to the data.  You'd need to specify a model, and then look at the coefficients of that model.  Do you have a sample dataset we can work with?

Comment: Am I missing something? OP asked about 55 vs 40 each out of 100. Then from `prop.test(c(55,40),c(100,100), correct = F)$p.val`, I get
 0.03367207, so signif diff at 5% level.

Comment: @BruceET Oops, must have thought OP said 50 and not 55.  Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for edit.

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect.

Comment: As for the regression, I'm not sure how to present it on this site. Hearing that the statistical analysis must be done on a more upstream step is useful to know though. I'm going to hunt through the R program that I used to calculate the CIs and see if there are more comparative functions available.

Comment: @Daniel if you found this helpful, please click the checkmark to accept the answer,